# AttributeError: 'WordNetCorpusReader' object has no attribute 'get_synsets_from_word'

Tags: python, nltk, arabic, wordnet

when using arabic wordnet in python , I follow this post 
 [Import Arabic Wordnet in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522161/import-arabic-wordnet-in-python)

and when run this command `wn.get_synsets_from_word(u"جَمِيل")`
raise AttributeError: 'WordNetCorpusReader' object has no attribute 'get_synsets_from_word'
how solve this error and use arabic wordnet correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Arabic Wordnet has no relation to Wordnet but the name. Wordnet has not that function `wn.get_synsets_from_word`. You should download Arabic Wordnet from [here](http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/awn/AWNDatabaseManagement.py.gz).

Comment: I download Arabic wordnet "AWNDatabaseManagement.py" and run it correctly . how use it for my own ?  and how using it to run this command wn.get_synsets_from_word(u"جَمِيل")

Comment: follow what explained in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522161/import-arabic-wordnet-in-python

Comment: I download Arabic wordnet "AWNDatabaseManagement.py" and run it correctly ,but when run this command wn.get_synsets_from_word(u"جَمِيل") raise AttributeError: 'WordNetCorpusReader' object has no attribute 'get_synsets_from_word' how solve this error and use arabic wordnet correctly?

Comment: @ bigOTHER thanks it run ok, I just start using AWN do you have any thing help my in use it ?

Comment: @EmanNaguib Actually AWN lacks real documentation, if any issue , ask in   Stackoverflow and ping me

Comment: @EmanNaguib Welcome, Please consider  to mark the other answer as accepted then upvote both,.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34821932/1327005